# How to grep and cut numbers from a file and sum them

Tags: text-processing, grep, logs, cut, numeric-data

I have a log file. For every line with a specific number, I want to sum the last number of those lines. To grep and cut is no problem but I don't know how to sum the numbers. I tried some solutions from StackExchange but didn't get them to work in my case.

This is what I have so far:

```bsh
grep "30201" logfile.txt | cut -f6 -d "|"
```

30201 are the lines I'm looking for.

I want to sum the last numbers 650, 1389 and 945

The logfile.txt

```
Jan 09 2016|09:15:17|30201|1|SL02|650
Jan 09 2016|09:15:18|43097|1|SL01|945
Jan 09 2016|09:15:19|28774|2|SB03|1389
Jan 09 2016|09:16:21|00788|1|SL02|650
Jan 09 2016|09:17:25|03361|3|SL01|945
Jan 09 2016|09:17:33|08385|1|SL02|650
Jan 09 2016|09:18:43|10234|1|SL01|945
Jan 09 2016|09:21:55|00788|1|SL02|650
Jan 09 2016|09:24:43|03361|3|SB03|1389
Jan 09 2016|09:26:01|30201|1|SB03|1389
Jan 09 2016|09:26:21|28774|2|SL02|650
Jan 09 2016|09:26:25|00788|1|SL02|650
Jan 09 2016|09:27:21|28774|2|SL02|650
Jan 09 2016|09:29:32|30201|1|SL01|945
Jan 09 2016|09:30:12|34032|1|SB03|1389
Jan 09 2016|09:30:15|08767|3|SL02|650
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can take help from `paste` to serialize the numbers in a format suitable for `bc` to do the addition:

```
% grep "30201" logfile.txt | cut -f6 -d "|"
650
1389
945

% grep "30201" logfile.txt | cut -f6 -d "|" | paste -sd+
650+1389+945

% grep "30201" logfile.txt | cut -f6 -d "|" | paste -sd+ | bc
2984
```

If you have `grep` with PCRE, you can do it with `grep` alone using postive lookbehind:

```
% grep -Po '\|30201\|.*\|\K\d+' logfile.txt | cut -f6 -d "|" | paste -sd+ | bc
2984
```

---

With `awk` alone:

```
% awk -F'|' '$3 == 30201 {sum+=$NF}; END{print sum}' logfile.txt        
2984
```

- `-F'|'` sets the field separator as `|`
- `$3 == 30201 {sum+=$NF}` adds up the last field's values if the third field is `30201`
- `END{print sum}` prints the `sum` at the `END`

Comment: Thanks! ```grep "30201" logfile.txt | cut -f6 -d "|" | paste -sd+``` dind't work for me, I got this errors ```(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M```.
But the solution with ```grep -Po '\|30201\|.*\|\K\d+'``` works. This is great!

Comment: Note that the `grep` solution does not care in what column the number is found, or whether the number is just a substring of a longer number.  The `awk` solution is safer in this respect.  The `grep` solution could be improved by _first_ cutting and the matching the number at the start of the line (followed by `|`) with proper anchoring.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing really wrong with your grep and cut command. You could make it more robust by using "|30201|" as the search pattern. The issue then is dealing with the output.

Using bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
# get the output as a bash array and add the elements
nums=( $(grep "|30201|" logfile.txt | cut -f6 -d "|") )
total=0

for i in ${!nums[@]}
    do
    total=$(($total+${nums[i]}))
    done
echo $total
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
pa=0 ; s=0 ; 
while read a b ; do \
  if [ "$a" == "$pa" ] ; then \
    s=$(($s+$b)) ; 
   else 
    if [ "$pa" != 0 ] ; then \
      echo $pa $s ; 
    fi ; 
    pa=$a ; s=$b ; 
  fi ; 
done < <(cat j.txt | awk -F'|' '{printf("%s %s\n",$3,$6)}' | sort -n) 
echo $pa $s
```

Init Previous A and SUM

Cut down the input to fields 3 and 6 and sort them by number

Loop as long as field 3 stays the same, add field 6 to the SUM

if field 3 changes but the Previous A is not 0, output the Previous A and the SUM and reinit Previous A to a and SUM to last field 6 read.

Output last Previous A and SUM.

Output of the given input:

```
00788 1950
03361 2334
08385 650
08767 650
10234 945
28774 2689
30201 2984
34032 1389
43097 945
```

Comment: Given you are using awk anyway to select the third and sixth columns, you should go the extra steps and sum things inside awk. This would give you something like `awk -F'|' '{s[$3]+=$6}END{ for (i in s) { print i, s[i] }}' | sort` - GNU awk has a builtin `asort` which could also be used rather than an external sort.

Answer (score 0):

One little tool I keep around I call sumcol

```
#!/bin/sh
# Icarus Sparry. Free for any use.
C=${1:?"missing required column number"}
shift
awk '{s+=$'"$C"'} END { print s }' "$@"
```

which adds up the whitespace delimited column you provide. Whilst I would write (as @heemayl does)

```
awk -F'|' '$3 == 30201 {s+=$6} END{ print s}' logfile.txt
```

for the OP's problem, he could use

```
grep "30201" logfile.txt | cut -f6 -d "|" | sumcol 1
```

or

```
grep "30201" logfile.txt | tr "| " " _" | sumcol 6
```